# How to embed webview inside another widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, webview, cross-platform, flutter

I've tried to embed webview inside another widget in Flutter and I found some libraries.

- [First Library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)
- [Second Library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_web_view)

But all of libraries I found can only launch webview as a new activity.

Comment: As others said it's not possible yet. Just show it on 1 whole screen by setting AppBar properties and put title to it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a WebView, MapView, video, camera, etc. inline in a Flutter widget tree is not currently supported. To my understanding, they're working on this currently.

See these GitHub pull requests:

- [Add texture support (eg video, camera) #4159](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/4159)
- [Add backend texture support (eg video, camera) #12525](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/12525)

**Edit #1:** The PRs have landed, and there's a [WIP plugin](https://github.com/sigurdm/video_player) of embedding a native video control inside a Flutter widget tree. To my understanding, WebView / MapView etc. require dispatching the touch/gesture events to the native counterparts, and they're not ready yet.

Comment: Correct. That's not possible yet.